# UPDATE an imploded multiple selection into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem while updating a  to database, It happens to add the new value beside the old value into the database for example

- Current Database Tags: tag1,tag2
- Form GET Tags: [tag1][tag2]
- Form Edited Tags: [tag1][tag2][tag3][tag4]
- Updated Database Tags: tag1,tag2,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4

  ```
  GET
  $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = $id";
  $edit = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit)){$tags = $row['tags'];}
  POST
  $tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags'];
  $query = "UPDATE data SET tags= '$tags' WHERE id = $id";

  <form method="post" action="">
          <select id="tags" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
              <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) {echo "<option value'$tag' selected>$tag</option>";} ?>
              <option>tag1</option>
              <option>tag2</option>
              <option>tag3</option>
              <option>tag4</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit" name="update">Submit</button>
      </form>
  ```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- `$tags` is not an array. See the below statement in your `while()` loop,

  ```
  $tags = $row['tags'];
  ```

  So you can't use it in `foreach` loop like *that*. Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string and get the tags in an array, like this:

  ```
  $tags = explode(",",$row['tags']);
  ```

  And then use this `$tags` array in your form, which is explained below.
- Syntax error here,

  ```
  $tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags'];
                                    ^ missing closing )
  ```
- Even you get the tags as an array(as pointed above), you don't have to use *that* `foreach` loop either, it will unnecessarily append additional/redundant tags in your `<select>` element. better use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check the tag value is present in `$tags` array or not and make it selected accordingly
- `value` attribute is missing from `<option>` tags.
- Place the `SELECT` operation below the `UPDATE` operation, otherwise you'll get old tag values from the `SELECT` operation even if you update the tags using the form.

So your code should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags']);
    $query = "UPDATE data SET tags= '$tags' WHERE id = $id";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = $id";
$edit = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit)){
    $tags = explode(",",$row['tags']);
}

<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <select id="tags" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="tag1"<?php if(in_array('tag1', $tags)){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>tag1</option>
        <option value="tag2"<?php if(in_array('tag2', $tags)){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>tag2</option>
        <option value="tag3"<?php if(in_array('tag3', $tags)){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>tag3</option>
        <option value="tag4"<?php if(in_array('tag4', $tags)){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>tag4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="update">Submit</button>
</form>
```